# Convergence of alternating series based on prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I've been experimenting with some infinite series, and I've been looking at this one,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} {1\over p_k}$$
where $p_k$ is the k-th prime. I've summed up the first 35 terms myself and got a value of about 0.27935, and this doesn't seem close to a relation of any 'special' constants, except maybe $\frac12\gamma $.

My question is, has the sum of this series been proven to have a particular closed form? If so, what is this value?

Comment: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=59644&view=previous

Comment: More directly, see "[Prime sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html)" on _MathWorld_, or entry [A078437](http://oeis.org/A078437) in the Sloane's OEIS.

Comment: Here are some first $8250$ digits. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5805435/Alternating_prime_sum.txt Unfortunately, it is not $\dfrac{\gamma}2$

Comment: The Inverse Symbolic Calculator http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index has no suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, this series has an expansion given by the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A078437).  This series is mentioned in many sources, such as [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html), [Wells](http://books.google.ca/books?id=1MTcYrbTdsUC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=alternating%20reciprocals%20primes&source=bl&ots=9F8_K9RnX2&sig=UNsMOJkBu81RDZyezgWJUkMCFu4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VxC8ULDVC8bbyQHMoICIDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Robinson & Potter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00070TBXU) and [Weisstein](http://books.google.ca/books?id=aFDWuZZslUUC&lpg=PA2367&ots=4pdSsoBaeM&dq=alternating%20sum%20reciprocal%20primes&pg=PA2367#v=onepage&q&f=false).

These sources all seem to imply that, though the series converges, no known "closed form" for this sum exists.