# Newton's evaluation of $1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} - \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, math-history

How might have Newton evaluated the following series?

$$\sqrt{2} \, \frac{\pi}{4} = 1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} - \cdots$$

The method of the [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462803/showing-pi-2-sqrt3-1-1-51-7-1-111-13-1-171-19-cdots) applies by setting $x=\pi/4$ in the Fourier series for $f(x) = \pi/2 - x/2$ and then subtracting the extraneous terms (which are a multiple of the Gregory-Leibniz series for $\pi/4$).

I read that this series appears in a letter from Newton to Leibniz.  However, I do not have access the letter which appears in [this volume](https://www.cambridge.org/ec/academic/subjects/physics/history-philosophy-and-foundations-physics/correspondence-isaac-newton-volume-2?format=PB&isbn=9780521085991).

Comment: This question may be a better fit for hsm.se.

Comment: Presumably with something like$$\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}+\frac{1}{8n+3}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+7}\right) =\sum_{n\ge0}\int_{0}^{1}x^{8n}\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1-x^{4}\right)dx
 =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^{2}}{1+x^{4}}dx
 =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^{2}}{\left(1-x\sqrt{2}+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\sqrt{2}+x^{2}\right)}dx
 =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\pm}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1\pm x\sqrt{2}+x^{2}}
 =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{\pm}\left[\arctan\left(x\sqrt{2}\pm1\right)\right]_{0}^{1}
 =\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}{\sqrt{2}}
 =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: @J.G.  Thank you. I didn't even know about that forum.

Comment: @J.G.That's a very nice solution.  Thank you!

Comment: I believe you can find the letter (in Latin) at http://www.newtonproject.ox.ac.uk/view/texts/normalized/NATP00180 (searching on "tandem" will get you close to where the series appears).

Comment: There are many ways to get this series.  Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3699121/obtaining-a-series-that-converges-to-frac-pi2-sqrt2-using-fourier-serie?r=SearchResults) for yet another alternative.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick Mackinnon gives what appears to be the story in an article that appeared in the *Mathematical Gazette* in March 1992 (Vol. 76, No. 475), entitled "[Newton's Teaser](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3620373)."  He writes that Newton conjured up the poser, in fits and starts, in response to Leibniz's series

$$
1 - \frac13 + \frac15 - \frac17 + \cdots = \frac\pi4
$$

The other answers here are not off the mark, really.  Newton was able to evaluate—determine areas for—among other things, expressions of the form

$$
\int \frac{dx^{\eta-1}}{e+fx^\eta+gx^{2\eta}}
$$

(Actually, he used $z$ instead of $x$, but I'll use the more usual $x$, because that's what Mackinnon does in most of his exposition other than direct cites of Newton.)  He pointed out that by letting $\eta = 1$, $e = g = 1$, and $f = 0$, then the result can be used to evaluate Leibniz's series, and he further suggested that setting $\eta = 1$, $e = g = 1$, and $f^2 = 2eg$ (i.e., $f = \sqrt2$) enables the evaluation of the series in question:

$$
1 + \frac13 - \frac15 - \frac17 + \frac19 + \frac{1}{11} - \cdots
$$

Following Newton's suggestion, we have

\begin{align}
\int_{x=-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt2x+x^2}
    & = \int_{x=-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2
                                 +\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2} \\
    & = \left. \sqrt2 \arctan \left(
        \frac{x+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}{\sqrt2}\right) \right]_{x=-1}^1 \\
    & = \sqrt2 \left[ \arctan \left( \frac12 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \right)
                    - \arctan \left( \frac12 - \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \right) \right] \\
    & = \sqrt2 \left( \frac{3\pi}{8} + \frac\pi8 \right) \\
    & = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Newton apparently recorded in his worksheets the factorization

$$
1+x^4 = (1+\sqrt2x+x^2)(1-\sqrt2x+x^2)
$$

so evidently he means to evaluate the integral alternatively as

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\int_{x=-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt2x+x^2}
    & = \int_{x=-1}^1 \frac{1-\sqrt2x+x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx \\
    & = \int_{x=-1}^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx 
      - \cancel{\int_{x=-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt2x}{1+x^4} \, dx}
      \qquad \text{because $\sqrt2x$ is odd} \\
    & = 2\int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx \qquad \text{because this is even}
\end{align}

Combining these gives us

\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}
    & = \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \, dx \\
    & = \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^4} + \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x^2\,dx}{1+x^4} \\
    & = \int_{x=0}^1 1-x^4+x^8-x^{12}+\cdots \, dx
      + \int_{x=0}^1 x^2-x^6+x^{10}-x^{14}+\cdots \, dx \\
    & = \left. x-\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^9}{9}
                -\frac{x^{13}}{13}+\cdots \right]_{x=0}^1
      + \left. \frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^{11}}{11}
                            -\frac{x^{15}}{15}+\cdots \right]_{x=0}^1 \\
    & = 1+\frac13-\frac15-\frac17+\frac19+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{13}-\frac{1}{15}
      + \cdots
\end{align}

Mackinnon adduces some circumstantial evidence that strongly suggests Leibniz never cracked Newton's little chestnut.

Answer (score 4):

Although the question appears to be about how Newton historically did it, I'll convert a popular comment to an answer showing how techniques from his era, similar to those that handle the Gregory series, evaluate the series above:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}+\frac{1}{8n+3}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+7}\right)&=\sum_{n\ge0}\int_{0}^{1}x^{8n}\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1-x^{4}\right)dx\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^{2}}{1+x^{4}}dx\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^{2}}{\left(1-x\sqrt{2}+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\sqrt{2}+x^{2}\right)}dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\pm}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1\pm x\sqrt{2}+x^{2}}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{\pm}\left[\arctan\left(x\sqrt{2}\pm1\right)\right]_{0}^{1}\\&=\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\\&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the text mentioned, we see something interesting on page $156$, in note $(48)$. Transcribing it (you can find a screencap of the text [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ8qj.png)):

> On observing that $$1 + \frac 1 3 - \frac 1 5 - \frac 1 7 + \frac 1 9 + \text{etc.} = \int_0^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx$$ by expanding the integrand as an ascending series in $x$, we may suppose that Newton obtained his result by integrating the identity $$\frac{1}{e+fz+gz^2} + \frac{1}{e-fz+gz^2} = \frac{2e + 2gz^2}{e^2 + g^2 z^4} \text{ (on putting } 2eg = f^2 \text{)}$$ in two ways. Put $z \sqrt g = x \sqrt e$ and $-x\sqrt e$, respectively, in the two fractions on the left, and integrate from $0$ to $1$ with regard to $x$. Then, on combining the terms on the left, the identity gives $$\frac 1 2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1 + \sqrt 2 x + x^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx$$ By putting $1 + x \sqrt 2 = \tan \theta$, and integrating $\theta$ from $- \frac 1 8 \pi$ to $\frac 3 8 \pi$, the left side gives $\pi/2 \sqrt 2$, and the right is equal to the series. (Cf. Hofmann, p. $175$.) The series, when written $1 + (\frac 1 3 - \frac 1 5) - \frac 1 7 - \frac 1 9) + \text{etc.}$, leads to the next result in the letter.

Granted, I'm not sure if this is how Newton actually calculated it, and I haven't actually read this book thoroughly enough to say if it's what you're looking for (I just skimmed until I found what seemed relevant). Hopefully it's enlightening though.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very interesting and helpful.