# Alternating sum of inverse prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

It is well known that the sum of all inverse primes is divergent. But the alternating sum is convergent by the Leiniz criterion. To which known constant "a" does the sum converge?

$$a = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11} -+ ...$$

Comment: your wording implies that the answer is known, if not to you, then someone. My guess would be that nobody knows.

Comment: You will see an answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241728/convergence-of-alternating-series-based-on-prime-numbers

Comment: @gimusi I have looked at the proposed answer. It deals with the convergence only, which, as I said in my post is granted by the Leibniz criterion. My question asks if the limit is a known constant, or can be expressed by known constants.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A078437  Only the first few digits are known.  All currently known digits: $0.26960635197167\dots$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Look at the third answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2329044/505767

Comment: @gomusi I have found hint to a - negative - answer to my question following the comment of Pjonin here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity and completeness, I have put the information in the comments into an answer...

As mentioned, this series has an expansion given by the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A078437), which states that the most accurate known estimate of the limit is 0.26960635197167...

The references given therein, as well as others such as [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html), [Wells](http://books.google.ca/books?id=1MTcYrbTdsUC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=alternating%20reciprocals%20primes&source=bl&ots=9F8_K9RnX2&sig=UNsMOJkBu81RDZyezgWJUkMCFu4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VxC8ULDVC8bbyQHMoICIDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Robinson & Potter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00070TBXU) and [Weisstein](http://books.google.ca/books?id=aFDWuZZslUUC&lpg=PA2367&ots=4pdSsoBaeM&dq=alternating%20sum%20reciprocal%20primes&pg=PA2367#v=onepage&q&f=false) indicate that no known closed form of this limit is known, nor does it have its own special name or symbol.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifying contribution. This answers my question in the sense that the result of the sum has no name. The duplicate announcement is wrong, however, since the provided link does NOT give an answer to my question. I have explained this clearly in a comment, and I refrain from repeating myself.